# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi connected, but cannot access internet

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns

I'm having the following weird internet connection problem that I'm struggling to fix.

I have a working home wifi / internet connection. I have a phone and another windows based PC on the network, and both can connect to the internet fine. On my ubuntu based machine I could connect fine as well until a few days ago (impossible to say what changed, could be an update), now the wifi connection is made, but there is no internet. The weird thing is, if I set my phone up as a hotspot, and connect to it, it works, and I can access the wifi internet, using the phone as a sort of proxy. This leads me to believe there must be some sort of settings issue in Ubuntu, possibly DNS related.

Another weird thing is if I run a ping eg `ping 8.8.8.8` The connection is mostly dead, but every once in a while, I get a response. It will ping a couple times and then nothing again.

I've tried editing my `/etc/resolv.conf` files to manually set the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 as I've seen in a few suggested solutions, but no luck. I've also tried setting the names servers via the network manager GUI.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

What else could I look into?

Comment: Maybe something disturbs the Wi-Fi connection between your PC and your WLAN access point. An electrical device, a giant metal plate, your antenna is broken, etc..

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer, or the router?

Comment: I've rebooted my router and PC. I don't think the connection to the router is the problem either, WIFI is connected and signal strength is high. I've moved the laptop to various locations.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many possible solutions this command ended up working for me:

```
docker network prune
```

Can't say why or how docker was interfering with my network connection but this fixed the issue

Comment: it took almost a day to fix this one, finally, your solution worked :( I am also wondering.